# Import form web address, and save it for next time use

Tags: export, import

I can get some information by

```
data=Import["http://xxxx/xxx/xxxx", "XMLObject"];
```

Then I can get some informatin by Case function, just like th following:

```
Cases[data, XMLElement[
"a", {___, "href" -> s_}, {___, 
 XMLElement["span", {___}, {___}], ___, 
 XMLElement["span", {___}, {___}], ___}] :> {s}, {0, Infinity}];
```

After that, I save "data" in a .txt file, by

```
Export["data.txt",data]
```

But I want to reanalysis those data, so I import the data.txt, (I think it convenient for use),

```
data = Import["data.txt"]
```

but it don't work when I use Case function again. I don't know why, I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: data.txt was saved as plain text. Mathematica will therefore import it as a String. Export to data.m or specify the export format and import formats.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you, I tried xml format, it is good.